# Nested Loops "For" in Python : Order T

Tags: python

I'm beginner in Python.
I am having difficulty resolving my problem:

Using nested for loops, print a right triangle of the character `T` on
the screen where the triangle is one character wide at its narrowest point and seven characters wide at its widest point:

```
T
TTT
TTTT
TTTTT
TTTTTT
TTTTTTT
```

and

```
      T  
     TT
    TTT
   TTTT
  TTTTT
 TTTTTT
TTTTTTT
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try to do your homework yourself first. If you have any questions, your textbook, teacher, classmates, and Google will be happy to help. If they can't help (they can), ask SO.

Comment: English isn't my first language. And I'm new here. I hope the community can help me improve my Eng and my program skills.

Answer (score 5):

I won't write a code for you but I can give you some hints:

- nested loops means a loop inside another loop, in this case one loop is for iterating through consecutive lines, the second is to print characters in each line
- the second example needs the same as the first, but you also need to check index of the inner loop and decide whether print space or 'T' character

Answer (score 1):

I hope you already have got the answer :)

**Pattern # 1**

```
def triangle(n):
    for i in range(1, n +1):
        print ('T' * i).rjust(n, ' ')

triangle(7)

##Results >>>

      T  
     TT
    TTT
   TTTT
  TTTTT
 TTTTTT
TTTTTTT
```

**Pattern # 2**

```
def triangle1(n):
    for i in range(1, n +1):
        print ('T' * i)

triangle1(7)

# Results >>>>
T
TTT
TTTT
TTTTT
TTTTTT
TTTTTTT
```

**Pattern generation by using only for loops**

Here I have tried to generate the with the help of only for loops and will very generalized way. Purposefully I have not used any readily available functions so you can always optimize it further.

**Pattern # 1**

```
def triangle(n):
    # Iterate through number of columns
    for i in range(1, n +1):
        s = ""
        # Iterate through number of rows
        for j in list(range(i)):
            s += "T"
        print s

triangle(7)
```

**Pattern # 2**

```
def triangle1(n):
    # Iterate through number of columns
    for i in range(1, n +1):
        s = ""
        # Iterate through number of rows
        for j in list(range(i)):
            blank = ""
            # Generate 'blank spaces'
            for k in (range(n - i)):
                blank += " "
            # Generate 'T'
            s += "T"
        print blank + s

triangle1(7)
```

Comment: You can get these results using nested for loops as well - that you would be the good exercise for you. :)

Comment: The "rjust" method is new for me.My ebook don't say anything about that.

Comment: **rjust** - The method rjust() returns the string right justified in a string of length width. Padding is done using the specified fillchar (default is a space). The original string is returned if width is less than len(s). Please go through - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rjust.htm

Comment: i know that link :) but i have been downloaded a ebook.did you think that link is better than my ebook?

Comment: @JamesCornel - I have updated the answer with the nested loop example code as well - I hope it helps you. As you will see - you can always optimize that further. Best luck. :)

Comment: You are welcome @JamesCornel. You may like to think about minimize the number of lines in the code to some extend as still there is scope for improving the code for **NESTED FOR LOOPS**.